# Is there a word for special names given to people of a certain group

Tags: single-word-requests

Examples:

- People who work at Google are called *"Googlers"*
- Fans of the Green Bay Packers are called *"Cheese heads"*
- Readers of Robinhood enewsletter are called *"Snackers"*
- Hardcore fans of Harry Potter are called *"Potterheads"*

These are just several examples. This question was inspired by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/tylertringas/status/1258430699293597697).

Comment: Perhaps a **nickname**? Possibly a **tag**?

Comment: *Title*? *Designation*? How about [constellation](https://www.lexico.com/definition/constellation)?

Comment: Note that the duplicate question broadens to include devotees of say the Grateful Dead ('Deadheads').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The correct answer is accepted below. Why was this marked as a duplicate if this answer is not the answer of the so-called duplicate?

Comment: (1) 'Demonym' identifies 'people belonging to a particular place', not 'people belonging to a particular group', and is _not_ the correct answer to your question. Since you have brought this up, I'll add that you should not have accepted it. 'Googlers', 'Cheese heads', 
'Snackers' and 'Potterhead' are _not_ demonyms. (2) 'demonym' and other less incorrect suggestions appear at the duplicate. (3) The _question_ is the duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth according to the accepted answer on the duplicate, the answerer pointed out "Demonym is *not* limited to geographical implications", though they did not make it their answer. It is the accepted answer here, and it will remain the accepted answer here. This question will join many other questions on SE which have been incorrectly marked as duplicates by busybody members but still receive more traffic because they are more useful

Comment: You misquote. According to the accepted answer at the duplicate , " **According to textproject.org** the term Demonym is not limited to geographical implications". According to CED, AHD, Lexico, Merriam-Webster, Macmillan, Nordquist at ThoughtCo, Wikipedia and even UD, this broadening is not standard. And the term was possibly coined or revived in 1997 by Paul Dickson of Merriam-Webster.  Hiebert and Svec at TextProject give no supporting references or data; the prestigious works mentioned above have sampling procedures and usage panels. _And I repeat, the question has been asked before._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A term for people belonging to a particular place is called a "**[denonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym)**":

> A **demonym** or **gentilic** is a word that identifies residents or natives of a particular place, usually derived from the name of the place or that of an ethnic group.… Examples of demonyms include *Cochabambino*, for someone from the city of Cochabamba; *American* for a person from the country called the United States of America; and *Swahili*, for a person of the Swahili coast.